# Why do I get this error and warning? Error and warning is in the description

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I have a problem that I can't fix. 
I get the error:error: non-object type 'int ()' is not assignable
  read = b;
And the warning: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion returning 'int ()' from a function with result type 'int' [-Wint-conversion]
  return read;

And I want to return the value b to main and I want to know why it doesn't work. I hope you can help me.
Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int read()
{
  FILE *fptr;
  char b;
  fptr = fopen("./chat.txt","r");

  if(fptr == NULL)
  {
    printf("Something went wrong");
  }

  b = fgetc(fptr);
  while(b != EOF)
  {
    printf ("%c", b);
    b = fgetc(fptr);
  }
  fclose(fptr);
  read = b;

  return read;
}
```

Comment: You have a function named `read`, and you are attempting to assign a value to it as if it were a variable, and then attempting to return it as if it were a variable.

Comment: Note that [`fgetc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) returns an `int`. This is actually very crucial and important for that comparison against `EOF`.

Comment: just `return b` instead of `read = b; return read`.  But also make b an `int`.

Comment: And to top it all, there is a function named read other than yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the first response by Christian, you are trying to assign your function name ***read*** to the value ***b***.

You simply need to:

```
return b;
```

Looking at your code, it looks like it will just return ***EOF***, as that is the last value that ***b*** will have before you return.  Not sure why you would need to do that, so thought I would mention it.

You could improve it a little by using a do/while like:

```
do
{
    b = fgetc(fptr);
    printf ("%c", b);
} while( b != EOF );
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is quite correct.
This line of code:

```
read = b;
```

attempts to assign the value of `b`, which is a `char`, to `read`, which is a function returning an `int`.

Delete the line and just return `b`. The compiler will promote the `char` to an `int` for you. Or, better, change `b` to an `int`, because as you may not know (but as Some programmer dude pointed out above), `fgetc` returns an `int`.